# Rails how to associate params/ get params from another params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In this scenario has post_id from comments rescouce but i'd like to get the coomments in post constroller that just has id from post resource so, 
post_id in comments and id from post is the same id, so i've tried to associate both by

```
 def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end



  def set_comment_post

    @post = Post.find_by(post_id: set_post)
  end
```

well the log spits out the error

so please, someone would spare a tip on this?

[image: routes]
[image: log]

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment_post only: [:comments]


  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :update, :destroy], except: [:comments]
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy, :new]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json



  def comments

    @comments = @post.comments.order('created_at desc')
    render json: @comments
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create


    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    if @post.save

      render json: "Posted successfully", status: 201
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    if @post.update(post_params)

      render json: "Posted updated successfully", status: 200
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end



  private
  def set_user
    @current_user = User.find_by(params[:id])


  end

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end



  def set_comment_post

    @post = Post.find_by(:post_id => set_post)
  end





  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :user_id, :posts_count)
  end
end
```

**params passed by request**

```
 "/posts/" + this.props.match.params.post_id + "/comments",
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. `set_comment_post` makes no reference whatsoever to any comment.  Also, it's unclear even which controller you're showing here.  Please try to explain your question more clearly and post more relevant code.  It might be useful to actually see what params are coming through in this controller as well.

Comment: @lacostenycoder ok, just a moment.

Comment: I guess `set_comment_post` should do `@comments = Comment.where(post_id: set_post.id)`, but you are already assigning `@comments` on your comments action, question is so confusing. Try to be more clear when asking a question here, read stackoverflow guidelines too.

Comment: it's getting a little better but can you post an example of the params that actually get passed in your request?

Comment: @lacostenycoder yeah, a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why you need 2 methods which are doing the same thing but I would think what you want is

Only use `before_action` if you need it for multiple endpoints.  Also, don't suse both `[:only]` and `[:except]` just one or the other.  This should work:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :update, :destroy, :comments]
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy, :new]

  def comments
    @comments = @post.comments.order('created_at desc')
    render json: @comments
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    if @post.save
      render json: "Posted successfully", status: 201
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
      render json: "Posted updated successfully", status: 200
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private
  def set_user
    @current_user = User.find_by(params[:id])
  end

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def post_params
    # add comments attributes if our text field is called 'text'
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :user_id, :posts_count, comments_attributes: [ :id, :text ] )
  end
end
```

You may also need to set `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

```
class Post
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, allow_destroy: true

  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Then however you're handing the data on the front end you need to pass the post form with nested fields for comments. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Comment: lacostenycoder thank you, but the params that need pass to the request is the id, but can't pass the id to react becaue of the routes the comments is under post
or i can change the post_id to just id in the routes?

Comment: please post your routes.rb file

Comment: lacostenycoder thank you very much, but this problem, is a problem more because of react. is frustrating work with rails associated models and react

Comment: I've given you a valid answer to the question you've posted and fixed the problems in your controller.  If you need help with passing params correctly from JS / React, that should be a separate question.

Comment: however can you post your routes.rb as the controller is making assumptions that you use nested routes.